# Restrict all kinds of emojis in Text Field in flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am looking for a way using which there should be **no emoji character allowed** in the **`textfield`**

or else a way to find out if there is a emoji  present in a string or not  **[regex]**

any one way of it could workout.

I have gone through all the related questions and their solutions but they don't cover the entire use cases.

Answer (score 6):

Eventually I Found the solution to the query so posting the answer here.

For the **first part**
Restrict Emoji's in `textfield`

add below code inside your `textfield` widget.

```
inputFormatters: [
   BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(
     RegExp('(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')
],
```

this will prevent all kinds of emoji's from the textfield.

**2nd part**

`if there is a emoji present in a string or not [regex]`

below mentioned code will detect if any emoji is present in the string or not

```
if(string.contains(RegExp(r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])'))){
   // your code here
}
```

Comment: `BlacklistingTextInputFormatter` is deprecated. Now you need to use `FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny`